# NAB 3DS - JSON data not sending in full

Tags: javascript, json, payment-gateway

I'm in the process of integrating the National Australia Bank's payment gateway into a site and I've come across an issue that I can't seem to solve, before I explain the issue I've included a link to download their 3DS integration guide, the page in question is the second half of page 12.

3DS documentation: https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/nabtransact/downloadDocs.nab?doc=14

I have included a short and a long explanation, I think the short explanation should suffice but for those wanting the full picture you're welcome to it.

**Short explanation**

The payload that gets sent as a request only includes 1/3 of the parameters that I'm sending, I have console logged the data before it is sent and it's all there, but when I look in the network tab at the data that was actually sent, it only includes one parameter (cardholderInfo).

The actual payload is included further down the question in the 'Long Explanation', as well as the data that I'm sending.

The request is sent via an external JS file (also included below), so I can only control what the JSON object contains, and as it seemingly contains everything it needs to - I'm not sure what I can do, other than try to confirm that it is an external issue.

**Long explanation:**

Following the documentation, I'm making a call to `initAndStartThreeDS` with all of the information it requests, this request is then going to return to the callback specified in the call, which in this case is the `onRequestDataInputCallback` method, the example request can be seen here:

```
var sp3dsConfig = {
    clientId: providerClientId,
    iframe: iframeElement,
    token: orderToken,
    simpleToken: simpleToken,
    threeDSSessionId: sessionId,
    onRequestInputData: onRequestInputDataCallback,
    onThreeDSResultsResponse: onThreeDSResultsResponseCallback,
    onThreeDSError: onThreeDSErrorCallback
};
```

The documentation then states the following to describe what the contents of the `onRequestInputDataCallback` method should be:

> onRequestInputData callback will collect relevant information from customer to be used in an EMV 3D Secure Authentication
> request. onRequestInputData callback is executed prior to an HTTP request initiated by EMV 3D Secure javascript. **The callback should return as JSON object with the following details.**

Now there is a table that I'll summarise for you, but you're welcome to look at in the documentation yourself, the JSON object that the `onRequestInputData` callback should return has three mandatory parameters, they are:

- cardholderInfo
- accountData
- billingAddress

The callback I've setup looks like this, I've replaced any sensitive information with 'X' as the actual content doesn't appear to be the issue:

```
function onRequestInputData() {
    var data = {
        billingAddress:{
            streetAddress: 'X', 
            city: 'X', 
            state: 'X', 
            country: 'X', 
            zipCode: 'X'
        },
        cardholderInfo:{
            cardNumber: '4444XXXXXXXX1111', 
            cardExpiryMonth: '07',  
            cardExpiryYear: '24', 
            cardholderName: 'Test',
        },
        accountData:{
            emailAddress: 'test@test.com',
        },
    };
    return data;
}
```

Now that I've explained all of that, I can start to explain what the actual issue is.

**The Issue**

So (in short), the `onRequestInputData` method is called when I make a call to `initAndStartThreeDS` using the data contained in `sp3dsConfig`, and needs to contain specific data, which it does.

The data that actually gets sent in the payload, only contains one of the three parameters however, `cardholderInfo`.

Here is the actual payload from DevTools:

```
data: {"cardholderInfo":{"cardNumber":"4444333322221111","cardExpiryMonth":"07","cardExpiryYear":"24","cardholderName":"Test Test"}}
```

The actual request that gets sent (as a result of the call to `initAndStartThreeDS` is external on NAB's side, I have the actual JS file and dug through it but I can't see why it would only send 1/3 of the parameters.

External JS: https://demo.transact.nab.com.au/threeds-js/securepay-threeds.js

**My Thinking**

I've tried re-formatting the JSON numerous ways, stripping out some of the parameters to try and get the payload to display anything other than `null` or `cardholderInfo`.

If I remove the 'cardholderInfo' parameter the data that gets sent is 'null', so it seems to specifically ignore any other parameter except that one, despite the documentation needing all three for a successful request, so unsurprisingly the request is ultimately failing.

The error I receive as well is quite ambiguous, the code is 180 and the documentation's description is as follows:

> Might be due to:
> Card brand used is not supported for EMV 3D
> Secure.
> Connection issue between 3DS server and Directory
> Server.
> Mandatory field is incorrectly provided.

As far as I can see there are three possibilities:

1. I'm doing something wrong.
2. The external JS they're using is filtering out the rest of the data somehow before the request is sent.
3. All of data is being sent and the developer console is wrong, in this scenario I imagine that either their 3DS service would also either need to be down or there's an issue with the data I'm sending (otherwise there would be no issue).

Any help at all would be appreciated, and if any of the above needs clarifying I'm more than happy to.